# trying to store an array of pointers

Tags: c

```
struct match
{
    char men[64];
    char women[64];
    char menNum[1000];
    char woNum[1000];
};

void printOut();
int matchMaking(struct match* p, struct match* q, int k);
int main(void)
{
    FILE* fin;
    FILE* fout;
    fin = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fout = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    int matchNum = 0;
    int size;
    int i;
    int j;
    int a;
    struct match* ptrName;
    struct match** ptrNum;
    char* str;
    char temp[800];

    if(fin == NULL)
        printf("Cannot Find File");

    fgets(temp, 800, fin);
    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    str = (char*)strtok(temp, " \n");
    size = atoi(str);
    printf("Size = %d\n", size);

    ptrName = (struct match*)malloc(size*sizeof(struct match));
    ptrNum = (struct match**)malloc(size*sizeof(struct match*));

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        fgets(temp, 800, fin);
        str = (char*)strtok(temp, " \n");
        matchNum = atoi(str);
        printf("Match Num = %d\n", matchNum);
        fgets(temp, 800, fin);
        strcpy(ptrName->men, temp);
        printf("Name = %s\n", ptrName->men);
        fgets(temp, 800, fin);
        strcpy(ptrName->women, temp);
        printf("Name = %s\n", ptrName->women);

        for(j = 0; j<matchNum; j++)
        {
            fgets(temp, 800, fin);
            strcpy(ptrNum[j]->menNum, temp);
            printf("Men Num = %d\n", ptrNum[j]->menNum);
        }
```

when debugging I keep getting a segmentation fault as an error

Comment: Where does your program halt?  Have you attached a debugger to find out?  Can you reduce the code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem?  The Stack Overflow community is not a debugger.

Comment: not sure how to do that but the problem lies in my for loop i'm just don't know why I am getting a segmentation fault. i wrote a similar program a couple weeks ago and it works there

Comment: what prints out before you get the seg fault?

Comment: it prints the names out but not the numbers, it just crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coarsely, I'd say the problem is here:

```
ptrNum = (struct match**)malloc(size*sizeof(struct match*));
```

What you really want is enough memory for `size` number of `struct match`, not `size` number of pointers.  Then you want to index into that space.

Effectively, you should do something like

```
struct match* ptrNum = malloc(size*sizeof(struct match));
```

This gives you a block of memory for `size` number of the structs and gives you a pointer to the first one.  You can use the shorthand "array" notation to index into this memory, so `match[0]` gives you the struct at position 0 in the "array" and `match[j]` gives you record at the *j*-th position.

Also note, `match[j]` gives you back the actual memory, so you won't want to use pointer notation:

```
strcpy(ptrNum[j].menNum, temp);
```

Comment: thank you that helped out a lot, i was getting ready to throw my CS1 book through my monitor

Answer (score 0):

You allocate an array of pointers, but you never actually set those pointers to anything! Your call to `strcpy(ptrNum[j]->menNum, temp);` will write to a random address since each one of your entries in ptrNum[] is uninitialized.